# Why do I get a E474: Invalid Argument history=... when I set a history size greater than 10000?

Tags: vim, config

In my .vimrc I am trying to set a very large history size. But whenever I try a number greater than 10,000, I get an invalid argument error like:

`E474: Invalid argument: history=10001`

It works fine for numbers not greater than 10000.

--

Output of vim --version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Aug  4 2016 15:30:16)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-2152
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        -toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.24.0_1/lib/perl5/5.24.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc -F/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks -framework Python   -lruby.2.3.0 -lobjc -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib
```

--

My complete .vimrc

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => General
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Enable filetype plugins
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

" Set to auto read when a file is changed from the outside
set autoread

" With a map leader it's possible to do extra key combinations
" like <leader>w saves the current file
let mapleader = "\\"
let g:mapleader = "\\"

" Fast saving
nmap <leader>w :w!<cr>
nmap <leader>q :q<cr>
nmap <leader>wq :wq<cr>
nmap <leader>Q :q!<cr>
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => VIM user interface
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Set 7 lines to the cursor - when moving vertically using j/k
set so=7

" Turn on the WiLd menu
set wildmenu

" Ignore compiled files
set wildignore=*.o,*~,*.pyc

"Always show current position
set ruler

" Height of the command bar
"set cmdheight=2

" A buffer becomes hidden when it is abandoned
set hid

" Configure backspace so it acts as it should act
set backspace=eol,start,indent
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l

" Ignore case when searching
"set ignorecase

" When searching try to be smart about cases 
set smartcase

" Highlight search results
set hlsearch

" Makes search act like search in modern browsers
set incsearch

" Don't redraw while executing macros (good performance config)
set lazyredraw

" For regular expressions turn magic on
set magic

" Show matching brackets when text indicator is over them
set showmatch
" How many tenths of a second to blink when matching brackets
set mat=2

" No annoying sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
"set t_vb=
"set tm=500

set nocompatible
" Sets how many lines of history VIM has to remember
set history=10000

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Colors and Fonts
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Enable syntax highlighting
syntax enable

colorscheme desert
set background=dark

" Set extra options when running in GUI mode
if has("gui_running")
    set guioptions-=T
    set guioptions+=e
    set t_Co=256
    set guitablabel=%M\ %t
endif

" Set utf8 as standard encoding and en_US as the standard language
set encoding=utf8

" Use Unix as the standard file type
set ffs=unix,dos,mac

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Text, tab and indent related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab

" Be smart when using tabs ;)
"set smarttab

" 1 tab == 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

" Linebreak on 500 characters
"set lbr
"set tw=500

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
set wrap "Wrap lines

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Visual mode related
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Visual mode pressing * or # searches for the current selection
" Super useful! From an idea by Michael Naumann
vnoremap <silent> * :call VisualSelection('f')<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :call VisualSelection('b')<CR>

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Moving around, tabs, windows and buffers
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Treat long lines as break lines (useful when moving around in them)
map j gj
map k gk

" Map <Space> to / (search) and Ctrl-<Space> to ? (backwards search)
map <space> /
map <c-space> ?

" Disable highlight when <leader><cr> is pressed
map <silent> <leader><cr> :noh<cr>

" Smart way to move between windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l

" Close the current buffer
"map <leader>bd :Bclose<cr>

" Close all the buffers
"map <leader>ba :1,1000 bd!<cr>

" Useful mappings for managing tabs
map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>to :tabonly<cr>
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove

" Opens a new tab with the current buffer's path
" Super useful when editing files in the same directory
map <leader>te :tabedit <c-r>=expand("%:p:h")<cr>/

" Switch CWD to the directory of the open buffer
map <leader>cd :cd %:p:h<cr>:pwd<cr>

" Specify the behavior when switching between buffers 
try
  set switchbuf=useopen,usetab,newtab
  set stal=2
catch
endtry

" Return to last edit position when opening files (You want this!)
autocmd BufReadPost *
     \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
     \   exe "normal! g`\"" |
     \ endif
" Remember info about open buffers on close
set viminfo^=%

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Spell checking
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Pressing ,ss will toggle and untoggle spell checking
map <leader>ss :setlocal spell!<cr>

" Shortcuts using <leader>
map <leader>sn ]s
map <leader>sp [s
map <leader>sa zg
map <leader>s? z=

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Misc
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Remove the Windows ^M - when the encodings gets messed up
"noremap <Leader>m mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm

" Quickly open a buffer for scripbble
map <leader>n :tabedit ~/.vim_buffer<cr>

" Toggle paste mode on and off
map <leader>pp :setlocal paste!<cr>

" Use JS syntax highlighting for JSON
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.json set ft=javascript

" JSON pretty printer: edits the current buffer, revert before
" quitting
map <leader>json :%!jq '.'<cr>
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Helper functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
function! CmdLine(str)
    exe "menu Foo.Bar :" . a:str
    emenu Foo.Bar
    unmenu Foo
endfunction

function! VisualSelection(direction) range
    let l:saved_reg = @"
    execute "normal! vgvy"

    let l:pattern = escape(@", '\\/.*$^~[]')
    let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")

    if a:direction == 'b'
        execute "normal ?" . l:pattern . "^M"
    elseif a:direction == 'gv'
        call CmdLine("vimgrep " . '/'. l:pattern . '/' . ' **/*.')
    elseif a:direction == 'replace'
        call CmdLine("%s" . '/'. l:pattern . '/')
    elseif a:direction == 'f'
        execute "normal /" . l:pattern . "^M"
    endif

    let @/ = l:pattern
    let @" = l:saved_reg
endfunction


" Returns true if paste mode is enabled
function! HasPaste()
    if &paste
        return 'PASTE MODE  '
    en
    return ''
endfunction

" Don't close window, when deleting a buffer
command! Bclose call <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
function! <SID>BufcloseCloseIt()
   let l:currentBufNum = bufnr("%")
   let l:alternateBufNum = bufnr("#")

   if buflisted(l:alternateBufNum)
     buffer #
   else
     bnext
   endif

   if bufnr("%") == l:currentBufNum
     new
   endif

   if buflisted(l:currentBufNum)
     execute("bdelete! ".l:currentBufNum)
   endif
endfunction
```

Comment: Did you even read `:help 'history'`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that. But just checked, couldn't find anything relevant. Sorry, am I missing somethinng, @romainl ?

Comment: Yes, you missed the part that says that the upper limit is 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @romainl pointed out in the comments, the upper bound is 10,000 commands. So I guess that's it.